# Integrating mailchimp with CRM

Tags: php, integration, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Need to get campaign_id with the list_id that I've got. My goal is to get all the campaign data and then sort out using the list_id. I have been able to retrieve the campaign response body, but somehow failing to get the campaign list_id. Any help or a different approach would be appreciated. Sharing my code and mailchimp api related reference.

MailChimp api ref:

```
"campaigns": [
    {
      "id": "42694e9e57",
      "type": "regular",
      "create_time": "2015-09-15T14:40:36+00:00",
      "archive_url": "http://",
      "status": "save",
      "emails_sent": 0,
      "send_time": "",
      "content_type": "template",
      "recipients": {
        "list_id": "57afe96172",  // this is required
        "segment_text": ""
      },
```

My Progress:

```
public static function getCampaignID($list_id){
    $MCcampaigninfo = self::$mc_api->get("/campaigns"); // gives a response consisting 3 rows, required value is in 1st row, which is an array
    foreach ($MCcampaigninfo as $key => $value) {
        if ($value[8]->'list_id' == $list_id) { //under the 'campaign'array, we need the 9th position property 'recipient'
            $campaign_id = $value[12]->'id';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so `$mc_api->get("/campaigns");` gives back json?

Comment: yeah, https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#%20

Comment: you you wan't all the id's of all campaigns?

Comment: Is there any other way I can find a match with my 'list_id' ?

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes the response of `$mc_api->get` is equal to the JSON you showed in your example

```
public static function getCampaignID($list_id) {
    $campaigns = json_encode(self::$mc_api->get("/campaigns"), true);
    $campaignIds = [];
    foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {

        //if the list_id matches the current campaign recipients['list_id'] add to the array
        if ($campaign['recipients']['list_id'] === $list_id) {
            $campaignIds[] = $campaign['id'];
        }
    }

    //return an array with campaignIds
    return $campaignIds;
}
```

Comment: I realized this code would work. Tried it, but gives the same output as my code, crm gets stuck with a 500 error.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. The api structure seems different in reality from their documentation. Thanks for all the help. Posting my updated code.

```
public static function getCampaignID($list_id){
    $MCcampaigninfo = self::$mc_api->get("/campaigns");     
    foreach ($MCcampaigninfo as $key => $campaign) {
        if($key == campaigns){
            foreach ($campaign as $key2 => $clist) {
                foreach ($clist as $key3 => $recip) {
                    if($key3 == id){
                        $campaign_id = $recip;
                    }
                    elseif($key3 == recipients){
                        foreach($recip as $key4 => $listid){
                            if($key4 == list_id){
                                if($listid == $list_id){
                                    return $campaign_id;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use nested foreaches like this, write it in a way i did, by directly accessing key's in the array structure (from json)